# Google Analytics: event tracking sitewide but generating unique URLs

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I have an online form on my website sitewide and want to use event tracking in Google Analytics in order to see the number of clicks on the submit button.

What should I do to make Google Analytics display each URL separately for this event?

In other words: I want to see how many clicks each page has for this event.

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just view the event in Google Analytics and then use 'Event Category' as the primary dimension and then add 'Page' as a secondary dimension?

This would then display one page (URL) per row, per event detailing how many event clicks occurred for each page. Does that cater for your data requirements?

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution, let me see if I can make a drill down. Thanks!